# findByNameContainingIgnoreCase -not working in case of GremlinRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, gremlin, graphdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to use findByNameContainingIgnoreCase while working on GremlinRepository... but it is throwing error like - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported keyword: CONTAINING (1): [IsContaining, Containing, Contains]

Even not working for any findByNameLike(String name) etc but working if using findByName(String name)

**Model Class: Product.java**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Vertex
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String key;
    
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    private String lastModifiedTimestamp;
    private String createdBy;
    private String createdTimestamp;
    
    private Map<String,String> properties;
}
```

**Repository Class: ProductRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends GremlinRepository<Product, String>{
    List<Product> findByName(String name);
    List<Product> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);  
}
```

**POM.XML:**

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-gremlin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Exception:**

```
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.864Z] 06-29-2021 12:43:08.863 [32m[pool-2-thread-6][0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m c.c.ei.s2m.service.ProductsService.findAllProduct - Error Fetching all products
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.865Z] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported keyword: CONTAINING (1): [IsContaining, Containing, Contains]
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.866Z]      at com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin.query.query.GremlinQueryCreator.create(GremlinQueryCreator.java:53)
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.867Z]      at com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin.query.query.GremlinQueryCreator.create(GremlinQueryCreator.java:22)
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.867Z]      at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119)
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.869Z]      at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95)
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.870Z]      at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81)
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.871Z]      at com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin.query.query.PartTreeGremlinQuery.createQuery(PartTreeGremlinQuery.java:38)
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.872Z]      at com.microsoft.spring.data.gremlin.query.query.AbstractGremlinQuery.execute(AbstractGremlinQuery.java:36)
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.875Z] Function "product" (Id: 94e69927-0027-4533-96ef-9b6015ece3b1) invoked by Java Worker
[2021-06-29T07:13:08.881Z]      at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
```

Comment: Please try this dependency <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-gremlin-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: As suggested by you tried with the same but no luck - same error - Error Fetching all products
[2021-06-29T09:25:55.262Z] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported keyword: CONTAINING (1): [IsContaining, Containing, Contains]

Comment: So in that case the microsoft library does not support that

Comment: any other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: This is the current code https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-gremlin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/spring/data/gremlin/query/query/GremlinQueryCreator.java

Comment: But there is an alternative https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin Maybe you want to check this out

Comment: Looks like not official, as no license given, tomorrow might if this repo closes then we will be in trouble as all will stop works.

Comment: That's the risk. But otherwise you cannot use contains

Comment: hmm understood, btw thanks a lot for your support.